# WPF Buttons: How to fix double clicking to trigger click event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF layout that consists of several buttons in a toolbar. When the "New Item" button is clicked, another row of text boxes is created. However, the delete button has to be clicked on two times in order for the last created row to be deleted. How would I make the click event for the "Delete" work for a single click and not a double click?

Here is the XMAL code:

```
<Window x:Class="Odan_Estimator_Tool.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Odan_Estimator_Tool"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Name="GridMain">
        <DockPanel>

            <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                <ToolBar Height="40" Margin="0,0,-1,0">
                    <Button Content="New Item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.512,0.521" Height="19" Click="NewItem" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="19" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="DeleteItem"/>
                    <Button Content="Calculate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  RenderTransformOrigin="-0.203,0.604" Height="19" Margin="0,9,0,0" />


                </ToolBar>


            </ToolBarTray>


        </DockPanel>




        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="606,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176"/>
        <Label Content="Item #" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="145"/>
        <Label Content="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="226"/>
        <Label Content="Unit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.725,-4.203" Height="26" Width="102"/>
        <Label Content="Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="493,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="2.705,2.641" Height="26" Width="113"/>
        <Label Content="Est. Qty" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="611,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="4.5,1.203" Height="26" Width="158"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="259,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="155,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="488,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" RenderTransformOrigin="1.403,0.47"/>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="245" Margin="914,154,-506,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792"/>



    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the C# code with the Delete function at the bottom.

```
    private void NewItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        //Generates new row of text boxes

        //Generates new item ID textbox
        TextBox item_box = new TextBox();
        item_box.Height = 23;
        item_box.Width = 161;
        item_box.Text = "";

        item_box.Margin = new Thickness(21, 76 + 23*counter, 0, 0);
        item_box.VerticalAlignment = 0;
        item_box.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

        items.Add(item_box);

        GridMain.Children.Add(item_box);

        //Generates new item ID textbox
        TextBox id_box = new TextBox();
        id_box.Height = 23;
        id_box.Width = 161;
        id_box.Text = "";

        id_box.Margin = new Thickness(21, 76 + 23 * counter, 0, 0);
        id_box.VerticalAlignment = 0;
        id_box.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

        items.Add(id_box);

        GridMain.Children.Add(id_box);



        counter++;
    }

    private void DeleteItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        GridMain.Children.Remove(items.ElementAt(items.Count - 1));
        items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);


    }
```

Comment: Not sure what your goal is here but... When you click "New Item" you are adding 2 identical textboxes but when you click "Delete Item" you are only removing that last one added. Should you be removing the last 2?